# add one day to date if it exceeded to a specific time in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, time

Here's my code for getting the time after adding specific time.. I don't know how to shift to tomorrow's date if the base_time is example: 4:50 PM and the 'default END TIME' is only 5:00 PM and I have to add 30 mins on the base_time. If I add 30 mins on the base, the `final date/time` is TOMORROW at 8:20 AM.. because the start of the day(work) is 8:00 AM.

Question : **How to do this? e.g. January 3, 2016 04:50:00 PM + (00:30:00) = January 4, 2016 08:20:00 AM.**

start time of work is at 8:00 AM

end is at 5:00 PM

Please help me on this. Thank you guys. I really need this.

```js
var time = "";
var total_seconds = 0;
var total_time = 0;
// ===================================================================
function toSeconds(timeToConvert){
  var hms = timeToConvert;
  var a = hms.split(':');

  seconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2]); 
  total_seconds += seconds;
}

 $('#btn').click(function () {

    var d = new Date();

    var month = d.getMonth();
    
    var day = d.getDate();
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    var hr = d.getHours();
    var min = d.getMinutes();
    var sec = d.getSeconds();



    if (sec <= 9) {
        sec = ('0' + sec);
    }
    if (min <= 9) {
        min = ('0' + min);
    }
    if (hr <= 9) {
        hr = ('0' + hr);
    }

    var base_time = hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
    toSeconds(base_time);
    // toSeconds("16:30:00");

    if ($('#acc1').is(":checked")) {
        time = "00:15:00";
        toSeconds(time);
    }
    if ($('#acc2').is(":checked")) {
        time = "00:30:00";
        toSeconds(time);
    }

    alert("total seconds = " + total_seconds);

    total_time = total_seconds;
    total_seconds = 0;

    
    
    if (total_time <= 61200) {
     var date = new Date(null);
        date.setSeconds(total_time);
        var date1 = day + "-" + (month+1) + "-" + year + " " + date.toISOString().substr(11, 8);
    }
    else {
     var da = new Date();

        var day1 = Number(da.toISOString().substr(8, 2)) + 1;  // Date1=currentday+1
        var month1 = da.getMonth();
        var year1 = da.getFullYear();

        total_time -= 61200;
        var new_time = 28800 + total_time; // Morning 8'o clock + remaining time
        da.setSeconds(total_time);
        var date1 = day1 + "-" + (month1+1) + "-" + year1 + " " + da.toISOString().substr(11, 8);
    }

    alert(date1);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label><input id="acc1" type="checkbox" name="acc">acc 1</label><br>
<label><input id="acc2" type="checkbox" name="acc">acc 2</label><br>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btn" name="btn" value="button">
```

edited and modified based on @Navaneethan answer. thank for that. But no I'm curious on how to consider the weekends? Those days without work. For example, Friday, the next day should be on Monday. The same for the changes in Months. How am I supposed to do that. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: those `if` statements seem unnecessary;  you might want to consider using one of the many time libraries like http://momentjs.com to help with these calculations instead of trying to split your time object into strings;  This implementation, even if you could make it work correctly, would suffer from various bugs, notably issues with Daylight Savings Time.

Comment: @Claies Thank you for the pointers. I am now using moment.js and date.js but my other problem is that how am I able to limit the last time of the day to only 5:00 pm not 11:49PM? if the resulted time is beyond 5:00pm it will automatically scheduled tomorrow. Just add the remaining time to 8:00am(start time of the day).

Answer (score 0):

I just modified your code... Try this. It may work

```
var time = "";
    var total_seconds = 0;
    var total_time = 0;
    // ===================================================================
    function toSeconds(timeToConvert) {
        var hms = timeToConvert;
        var a = hms.split(':');

        var seconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2]);
        total_seconds += seconds;
    }

    $('#btn').click(function () {

        var d = new Date();

        var hr = d.getHours();
        var min = d.getMinutes();
        var sec = d.getSeconds();

        if (sec <= 9) {
            sec = ('0' + sec);
        }
        if (min <= 9) {
            min = ('0' + min);
        }
        if (hr <= 9) {
            hr = ('0' + hr);
        }

        var base_time = hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
        toSeconds(base_time);

        if ($('#acc1').is(":checked")) {
            time = "00:15:00";
            toSeconds(time);
        }
        if ($('#acc2').is(":checked")) {
            time = "00:30:00";
            toSeconds(time);
        }

        alert(total_seconds);

        total_time = total_seconds;
        total_seconds = 0;

        var date = new Date();
        if (total_time <= 61200) {
            date.setSeconds(total_time);
            var date1 = date.toISOString().substr(11, 8);
        }
        else {
            var day1 = Number(date.toISOString().substr(8, 2)) + 1;  // Date1=currentday+1
            var month1 = date.getMonth();
            var year1 = date.getFullYear();
            total_time -= 61200;
            var new_time = 28880 + total_time; //Morning 8'o clock + remaining time
            date.setSeconds(total_time);
            var date1 = day1 + "-" + month1 + "-" + year1 + ":" + date.toISOString().substr(11, 8);
        }
        alert(date1);

    });
```

Comment: thank you! I got the idea, but it seems like it does not display the `right` time when it exceeded to 5:00 PM of the current day. It shows beyond 8:00 am tomorrow but not the exact time. Please help.

Comment: I think I know why the tomorrow's time is larger than expected. I'll try to configure that later. The new Date() changes the results.